# EAV - Add rows with null value if row does not exist

Tags: mysql

I have the following table storing data in the EAV model:

```
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id     | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| question_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| answer      | blob    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

With a table to hold the different types of question:

```
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| question | blob    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

As well as a users table:

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_name        | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

How would I write a query to insert a row with a null value for `answer` for each `question_id` that each user does not currently have a row for?

For example, if I have `question_id`s `1,2,3,4` and my table storing data looks like:

```
+--------------+---------------+--------+
| user_id      | question_id   | answer |
+--------------+---------+-----+--------+
| 1            | 1             | example|
| 1            | 3             | example|
| 1            | 4             | example|
+--------------+---------+-----+--------+
```

I want to insert a row that looks like :

```
+--------------+---------------+--------+
| user_id      | question_id   | answer |
+--------------+---------+-----+--------+
| 1            | 2             | NULL   |
+--------------+---------+-----+--------+
```

I tried something like this:

```
INSERT INTO profile_answers
(
    user_id,
    question_id,
    answer
)

SELECT
    id,
    profile_answers.question_id,
    null
FROM users
LEFT JOIN profile_answers ON profile_answers.user_id = users.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT answer 
    FROM profile_answers 
    WHERE user_id = id
    AND question_id IN (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') FROM profile_questions
    )
)
```

But I ended up inserting rows with a `question id` of 0.

Comment: Is `question_id` a `FK` to `id` of `profile_questions`?

Comment: Yes, the second table is a lookup table where `question_id` is a `FK` to `id` of `profile_questions`

Comment: Hence, you can use `profile_questions` to find missing `question_id`s per user.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos You can find the missing question ids easily, but you won't know which user they should belong to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've given this some thought, but I couldn't find anything better than using a cartesian product between users and questions, and a filtering subquery:

```
SELECT u.id, q.id
FROM users u,
questions q
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT *
  FROM profile_answers a
  WHERE a.question_id = q.id AND a.user_id = u.id
);
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86db67/4)